Confusion on the definition of the Christoffel symbols
A common way to introduce the Christoffel symbols is by defining them as determining how the basis vectors change when you translate along your coordinates:
$$\frac{\partial\hat{e}_{(\gamma)}}{\partial x^\beta}=\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}\hat{e}_{(\alpha)}$$
or equivalently,
$$\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\gamma}=\frac{\partial\hat{e}_{(\gamma)}}{\partial x^\beta}\hat{\theta}^{(\alpha)}$$
where $\hat{\theta}^{(\alpha)}$ is the basis one-form corresponding to the coordinate $x^\alpha$.
I understand this definition intuitively when it comes to working on a flat manifold, where vectors at every point can all be thought of as living in the same tangent space. However, say on the surface of a sphere, this is no longer true: different points have different tangent spaces. So how does it even make sense to talk about differentiating basis vectors like this? Why does this definition make sense for curved manifolds? After all, don't we need a sense in which we can compare vectors at different points in order to differentiate them?
This definition seems a bit disconnected from trying to relate tangent spaces on a curved surface and more related to accounting for certain choices of coordinates. Hence, I'm struggling to understand what makes it a "connection".

Yes,you're correct.
Let's consider a flat manifold,if I give you the coordinate lines,regardless its curved(like polar or more complex) or flat(like cartesian),you can exactly compute all $\Gamma$ right?
But on a curved manifold,you can't exactly compute them because as you said

different points have different tangent spaces.

So basically the philosophy is:We want,but we can't,so we add it.
And

Why does this definition make sense for curved manifolds?

this is just we define it like this,in general the connection is very arbitrary,see at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)
we have so many connections.
In fact if you just let all $\Gamma =0$,this is the trivial case of affine connection.
And the most intuitive connection may be the Levi-Civita connection for a metric manifold.
If we have a connection,we can derive its geodesic equation,this is the generalization of straight line on curved manifold.
If we have a metric manifold,we know the length between different points,but we still don't know what a striaght line is,because, again

different points have different tangent spaces
so we don't know how different tangent space are related.

But if we define the straight line(connection):the straight line is the shortest line(only defined by metric).This is how Levi-Civita connection works.
